# Disable another DHCP server

Tags: router, dhcp, dhcp-server

I'm using a home router with several devices connected to it.
DHCP area is something like 192.168.2.50 to 192.168.2.150.
Default gateway is 192.168.2.1.

However, when I connect to the network, I was being assigned 192.168.96.3 for some reason.

I log in to 192.168.96.1 and I see something like "CISCO SPA Configuration". Feels like this is a Cisco headset and I'm not sure of anyone using this device or broadcasting a new DHCP server. How should I go about disabling this?

Comment: It would help to know the models of your router and headset. Please efit your question to provide it

Comment: Do you (did you) have a Virtual Machine app running?  That could explain the large subnet difference.

Comment: Going from a question with details to a question with absolutely no details is a step in the wrong direction. You should address the comments and *add* more details to the question body.

Comment: Simply use Wireshark to see what is happening.

Comment: Look for and disconnect the rogue device from your network, done. Google tells you what a Cisco SPA is. Hint: it's not a heaset.

Comment: It's a phone adapter. Maybe it is acting as DHCP server because it is not configured? I think normally it should not be a DHCP server.